# Tabbing between Xcode projects?

Tags: xcode, macos, ide

Let us say that I have two Xcode projects open on a Mac and I am going back and forth between them. Is there any hot key that can do this (rather then constantly using the mouse). Something analogous to COMMAND + TAB to flip through applications.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> (above tab on US/en keyboards) will go through open windows in the current app. use shift to reverse the direction.

Comment: Note that this is not specific to Xcode - you can use this to cycle through windows in pretty much any app.