# Tabbing between Xcode project windows?

Tags: xcode

Basically I am supposed to press Command + the [`~] button that is above the Tab.

This question has been answered twice here:

[Tabbing between Xcode projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985534/tabbing-between-xcode-projects)

and

[Navigate Between Projects in XCode 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582629/navigate-between-projects-in-xcode-4-0)

But it just wont work for me, has anything changed in the xcode versions? or the way the mac behaves?
When I press this combination all I hear is the "invalid" sound.

I am using the newest Mac OS mountain lion.

Sorry if this belong to the super user stack overflow I just figured more Xcode users would be found here.

I can do the swipe on the mouse pad to bring the screen where I see all the active windows for the current application... but this is much slower than just tabbing between the 2 projects I'm usually working with.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked Xcode's key bindings? Have you checked the system preferences for key bindings?

Comment: yes, but I cant seem to find the one I want. What confuses me is that there was clearly a way to do this, where did it go to?

Comment: Maybe you already tried this, but in the key bindings of Xcode, there's a search box. If you just type the ` key, it will show you any key bindings that use that key. It looks like by default, there are only 2 - "Move Focus to Next Area" and "Move Focus to Previous Area". And in the System Prefs, you can click on "Keyboard", then select "Keyboard Shortcuts" to see if any match. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do I infer from your comment about using the three finger swipe (for [Mission Control](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4689)) that the second window is not on the same desktop as the other windows? The <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> sequence only jumps between windows on the same desktop, not between different desktops (which is not to be confused with two physical monitors, which you can jump between, if you have multiple monitors hooked up to your computer).

The inability of <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to not jump between desktops is a little curious, because <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, which jumps between apps, does go across desktops. If you want to jump between desktops, you can press <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to jump to desktop 1 or 2, respectively. It should be noted, though, that while that might be a good alternative when trying to jump between your two desktops, though it admittedly selects the last active window in that other desktop, not necessarily a window from your current app in that other desktop. Also <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> let you jump between desktops, too.

This is a Mac OS "feature", not an Xcode issue, I believe. The <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> ability to jump between windows (but not windows across Mission Control desktops) is the same behavior across the Mac OS.

---

**Update:**

If this keyboard shortcut is not working at all, in any app, even within a single Mission Control desktop, then you don't need to worry about Xcode settings, but rather focus your attention on the keyboard settings:

[image: keyboard shortcuts]

You might want to look at your "Move focus to the next window" keyboard shortcut. There have been reported problems of people with international keyboards not getting this to work properly, but by clicking on (and thereby selecting) the <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> graphic, you can try using different keyboard shortcut, and see if that does it for you.

Comment: the command + ` does nothing for me on any window, how do i enable it? (not on xcode, or not even on chrome) (and also, i only use one desktop)

Comment: YES! this is it, this is what i've been looking for!, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I have mountain lion as far as i know.
How about this?
control + down
You'll get the current application windows.
Below them there should be a horizontal list of recent projects for Xcode (both opened and closed). With arrows left or right choose the project (it should be highlighted with blue) and press enter.